# Как можно укротить анонимность?

Tags: c#, .net, архитектура, .net-core

В общем, пилю отчет, где данные собираются из разных источников, а потом все это соединяется между собой и все такое.

Так вот, в процессе этих соединений и вычислений получается множество промежуточных результатов в анонимных классах.

Так как они анонимны, то разбить метод на несколько методов я не могу, так как анонимные типы не передаются и в итоге получается мега-метод, где через какое-то время черт ногу сломит.

Собственно вопрос:

А какие у меня могут варианты красиво решить данную проблему?

Самое простое- это сделать по типу на каждый промежуточный результат, но эти классы будут использоваться только в одном месте и не хочется плодить сущности.

Использовать ValueTuple? Получаются слишком длинные сигнатуры.

Comment: у вас вопрос по коду, а кода нет.

Comment: @tym32167 да, но я думал, что на словах описал ситуацию.

Comment: Подобные оптимизации зависят от контекста. Вот вам встречный вопрос: `у меня есть 100 строк кода, в каждой строчке я вызываю какую то функцию и что то считаю. Результаты некоротых функций передаются как параметры в другие функции. Как мне заставить код работать быстрее?` - это просто как пример вопроса, который требует контекста.

Comment: _Так как они анонимны, то разбить метод на несколько методов я не могу_ - почему?

Comment: @Grundy Анонимные классы в методы не закинуть, если только в анонимные лямбды в рамках этого метода, или передавать как object, но это такое себе

Comment: @SultanovShamil, все зависит от метода

Comment: Попробуйте `dynamic`

Comment: вложенные приватные классы не решат вашу проблему? Можно даже отдельными файлами (partial), чтобы не загромождать код основного класса. А так да, из альтернатив только громоздкие кортежи либо dynamic (прощай контроль типов). Но это без контекста. При наличии более конкретных входных условий может и найдется что-то еще, но гадать не хочется.

Comment: @iluxa1810 а если все-таки попытаться создать минимальный набор необходимых классов, сколько по вашим расчетам выйдет классов?

Comment: Есть еще один вариант: возвращать из метода object и на стороне вызова кастить его в тот же самый анонимный тип. Может получиться громоздко, но все же.